# Can I put a package's LWC that uses other custom LWCs from the package in a flexipage for a custom object?

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, flexipages

We developed a package, with a fully lowercase namespace, that includes custom objects. We created an LWC, we'll call it "c-container". This LWC uses another LWC, we'll call it "c-child", in its template. Both components are part of the package.

If we drop the container component onto a flexipage for a standard or custom object everything works fine on the scratch orgs used in the package development.

However, when we install the package on a non-scratch org (or at least on an org that doesn't have the namespace of the package related to it), the custom object (and only custom object) flexipages do not render. Instead we see an error:

> **Looks like there's a problem.**
>
> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 565278946-283258 (308134562)

This is accompanied an exception in the browser console that references a function called "getFlexipageDescriptor".

What's up?

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a significant bug in the Lightning Platform infrastructure. While it should be possible to include the LWC component hierarchy in the flexipage it appears there's a namespace handling issue that prevents it. The workaround is as per a different [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SHvtQAG):

Create an Aura-based "wrapper" component that includes the necessary design attributes for the container's target config properties and that simply renders the LWC in its body then update the flexipages to use that aura wrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

We have hit this & opened a Case to get looked it. Been told it has been fixed but testing has not yet confirmed. I don't have details any detail on what has been done to fix it but no action requested on our side, just a re-test of the page & component that got this error.

Comment: OK, well I raised it on the Partner Forums with the LWC product manager. He said that "the team are looking at it". Not sure what status it is at. We first raised this with Salesforce about a week ago and got to the workaround day before yesterday.

Comment: @PhilW We got a fix that resolved our issue on this, think may have gone live over the weekend from what we saw.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try removing our workaround and see if it works. Perhaps I could try installing an older version of our beta package to see...